# General swap implementation in terms of byte swap

Tags: c++, c++14, swap, std

The current implementation for general swap in the standard library is something like

```
template <class T>
void swap(T& a, T& b) {
  T c(move(a));
  a = move(b);
  b = move(c);
}
```

I'm wondering whether I can do the following instead.

```
template <class T>
void swap(T& a, T& b) {
  unsigned char x;
  auto pa = reintepret_cast<unsigned char*>(&a);
  auto pb = reintepret_cast<unsigned char*>(&b);
  auto pc = pa + sizeof(a);
  while (pa != pc) {
    x = *pa;
    *pa = *pb;
    *pb = x;
    ++pa, ++pb;
  }
}
```

I think this implementation is better in terms of space usage, as it takes only one byte.

Comment: Regardless of other problems it may or may not have, time performance is likely to be worse, and is there really a reason to limit the general case to only using temporary space of one byte?  Only on the most restricted of systems would that be necessary.

Comment: The byte-at-a-time method will work but only for types that are POD.  It would not do the right thing for types that cannot be naively copied.

Comment: It also fails for atomic/volatile types which cannot be cavalierly reduced to single-byte moves.

Comment: *"better in terms of space usage, as it takes only one byte"* - CPU registers are likely to be 4 or 8 bytes wide: dealing in smaller sizes will be *less* efficient if anything.  And as a general rule, while you're just learning the language (as the question implies), trust the compiler to optimise better than you can, unless profiling proves you *have* to get involved.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner : You mean for types that are trivially copyable. PODness was a C++03 requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many considerations that need to be addressed when swapping classes.  For POD types, swapping bytes works correctly.  More complicated classes, however, may rely on invariants that byte-swapping won't respect.  For example, consider a reference to a member variable:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() : bar{}, barRef{bar} {};
    int  bar;
    int& barRef; // Expected to refer to the neighboring `bar`
};

int main()
{
    Foo f{};
    {
        Foo g{};
        byte_swap(f, g);
    }
    // `f` is now invalid: `f.barRef` is pointing to garbage
}
```

Comment: So, you are basically saying that `byte_swap()` does not respect `const`-modified members?

Comment: @Lingxi Not exactly.  I'm saying that the raw-value of members is only a piece of what makes a class valid.  There may be assumptions and invariants that byte-swapping won't respect.

Comment: I did not get exactly what the expression "swapping bytes is fine" means. It has the same performance, or just is a correct operation?

Comment: @Amadeus I meant it is a correct operation.  As for performance, you could benchmark different types of swapping yourself.  I doubt there'll be much improvement, but I've never tested it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider that every class can define what should happen when an instance is copied or moved by it's own. Sometimes a class may do something different then just move it's bytes. Maybe the class stores a pointer which is pointing to a member of the same instance. Just copying the bytes would breake the instace then.

---

I also thing that it will not make much difference. It is not really noticeable when the application needs 60 bytes more.